# Unable to find ChooserEventArgs class

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, camera

I want to open windows phone 7 camera, take a snap and then manipulate that picture. But the problem is when I try to override the `OnChooserReturn` function it gives me the error `no suitable method found to override` also when I want to capture what returns from the camera I use this :

```
ChooserEventArgs<PhotoResult> args = new ChooserEventArgs<PhotoResult>()
```

It gives me the error `The type or namespace name 'ChooserEventArgs' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)` although I am using these two directives

```
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Tasks;
```

What is the problem and how can I solve these issues?

Comment: Yes my reference is Mix 2010 video

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to use an old SDK or at least a guide based on an outdated SDK.  To have the phone launch the Camera and then to reference the captured image you use the `CameraCaptureTask`.  You will need the following Using statements:

```
using Microsoft.Phone.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
```

Somewhere in your code (presumably in a button click event) you do this to launch the camera:

```
CameraCaptureTask cct = new CameraCaptureTask();
cct.Completed += new EventHandler<PhotoResult>(cct_Completed);
cct.Show();
```

Then you handle the completed event like this (assuming you have an Image control named image):

```
void cct_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
{
    if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
    {
        BitmapImage bimg = new BitmapImage();
        bimg.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);
        this.image.Source = bimg;
    }            
}
```

Documentation Here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks.cameracapturetask(v=VS.92).aspx